# Beamer and the \pause command

Tags: beamer, pause

I'm creating a `beamer` presentation and I want to use the `\pause` command but I want the text after the `\pause`s to be completely invisible not just transparent. Is there any way to do this? I tried the `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` command but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default for beamer is `\setbeamercovered{invisible}`, but you may have used other themes or packages which have altered that setting and made `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`. You can override that again by issuing `\setbeamercovered{invisible}`at the right place in your presentation. I deliberately changed the setting at the beginning and overridden it later at the right place.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\begin{document}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item Hello World!
    \item Example Text 1
    \item Example Text 2
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item ahaha
    \pause
    \item aaahhaha
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You should get this:

[image]

instead of this:

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- Yes, you're right, the OP is just keeping people here guessing! No MWE?

Comment: I feel so dumb! I had a '\setbeamercovered{transparent}' farther down in my preamble than where I added the '\setbeamercovered{invisible}' I talked about in my question. Thank you guys for the help, everything is working nicely now! Sorry to keep you guys guessing.